# Pandas move column values to first row within same column if Nan

Tags: python, pandas

How do I go from this `df`,

```
     c0   c1   c2   c3 
0  5.99  NaN  NaN  NaN  
1   NaN   12  NaN  NaN                
2   NaN  NaN   44  NaN               
3   NaN  NaN  NaN   49
```

to this `df`,

```
     c0   c1   c2   c3 
0  5.99   12   44   49
```

That is,

- Move all non-NaN values into first row
- Keep all values in original column

Per column, there's just 1 non-NaN value.

Comment: Are the number of not `NaN` values guaranteed to be equal in all columns?

Comment: `df.bfill(0).dropna()`?

Comment: Per column, there's just one non-NaN value.

Comment: @Sandeep Kadapa: with `bfill(0)` indeed, not `bfill(1)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) with `axis=0` and `downcast='infer'` + [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df.bfill(axis=0, downcast='infer').dropna()

print(df)
     c0  c1  c2  c3
0  5.99  12  44  49
```

Without `downcast='infer'` you get all float data types:

```
print(df.bfill(0).dropna())
     c0    c1    c2    c3
0  5.99  12.0  44.0  49.0
```

Comment: What is the added value of `bfill (axis=0, downcast='infer')`? It seems to work fine as `bfill(0)`.

Comment: @LucSpan `downcat='infer'` converts potential integer values to int data type as you see if use `bfill(0)` then you get all float data types but using this some columns changed to int data type check it.

Comment: Was waiting for the time period to pass :-)

Comment: @LucSpan No problem.